# Two PostgreSql servers conflicting on same computer, with different TCP ports

Tags: database, postgresql, tcp, server

I am developing new application with PostgreSql as data server, and have installed Pg server via standard installation (Windows is my OS).  For testing purpose I did create separate data cluster and try to run separate postgres instance up on it.  For that job I have used initdb, pg_ctl and postgres programs that belongs to main installation.
Both server processes runs on localhost, first server on port 5432, and second on port 5433.
But, second server refuse to start while first process is running, and same thing happend with second server.  I am sure not to misuse port numbers, because I can connect to first server on port 5432, and to second on port 5433 (with PgAdmin and my application), but not at same time.
I use Postgres version 9.5 on Windows XP.
What may be wrong with this?

Comment: Could the reason be other than anything to do with the address to bind?

Comment: Check the logfile(s)

Comment: Output of `show data_directory;` for each of these?

Comment: @wildplasser It works now. When 1st server instance is active on port 5432, second refuse to start with msg: "could not start server". In logfile there is one new row: "FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment "Global/PostgreSQL.851401618": Permission denied".  Then I searched for that and found [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120595/postgresql-on-windows-fails-to-start-could-not-create-shared-memory-segment).  Then I changed dynamic_shared_memory_type to "none" and server did start (slower start but functional)!  Thank You for support, and also to Mike and Prabhu.